# Starling Feathers - Available features 101

Tags: android, actionscript-3, mobile, air, starling-framework

New to **Starling-Feathers**, before I start to develop my mobile app, I would like to know what are the best practice to develop the following features using **Feathers**:

1. Partial view slide - A part of the next view is shown and the user can drag to see it all. Could this be done with Feathers ScreenNavigator?
2. Sliding menu from the top
3. Dragging text elements with title pushing the last items

Since it is hard to describe I've added an animated gif to describe my goals. Thanks for all your advices

[image]

I would like to maximize the use of Feathers built in widgets and will appreciate code examples :)

Answer (score 1):

I think these are not that much hard to do in core flash or  you can also do it in Starling feathers too. YOu can use list item to do the third point (Dragging text elements with title pushing the last items) . 
First and second you can use it with tweening effect i think.

For the third one using feathers list.
(re formated post)

```
        private function addFeatherList():void{
            Flist = new List();
            Flist.width = 250; 
            Flist.height = 300;
            Flist.x = GAME_W/2 - Flist.width/2;
            Flist.y = sampText.height + 5;                               
            this.addChild( Flist );
            fontArr = Font.enumerateFonts(true);

            for (var i:int=0; i<fontArr.length; i++){           
               ListArr[i] = { text:Font(fontArr[i]).fontName } 
            }  

            var groceryList:ListCollection = new ListCollection( ListArr );
            Flist.dataProvider = groceryList;
            Flist.itemRendererProperties.labelField = "text";

            FeathersControl.defaultTextRendererFactory=function():ITextRenderer{ 
                var render:TextFieldTextRenderer=new TextFieldTextRenderer();
                render.textFormat = new TextFormat("Verdana",8,0xFFFFFF,false); 
                return render;
            }

            Flist.itemRendererFactory = function():IListItemRenderer              //list.itemRendererProperties.accessorySourceField     list.itemRendererFactory   
            {
                var renderer:DefaultListItemRenderer = new DefaultListItemRenderer();
                renderer.addEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED, onListTriggered);
                return renderer;
            }   
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I would like to maximize the use of the framework, Could you explain how can I achieve the 3rd effect with "items list"